# Manga where the MC returns to his world and can still use magic

Tags: story-identification, manga

The story starts off with the MC defeating the demon lord or something. After that the MC says farewell to a bunch of characters, and when he returns to his world, he meets up with his friend that's a girl in a fast food restaurant, who notices that the MC is giving off a different vibe. When he returns home he unconsciously uses magic, realizes he used magic and is confused since he's back in his world.
This all happens in like 2 chapters.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: I'm seeing "MC" written several times. What does it mean?

Comment: @Clockwork It's an abbreviation for Main Character

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for *Kikanshita Yuusha no Gojitsudan*

> In a fraction of a second, a university student, Kashiwagi Yuuya was summoned to another world and came back. Time didn’t pass in Japan, but Yuuya has completed the quest as a hero in another world and successfully returned. But to his surprise, he still retains his powers as a hero. Thus started the unordinary life of a hero in the present day.